# Domain Name troubleshooting

Tags: linux, domain-name

I have a question regarding how to troubleshoot a domain name, for example when my url is not working, how can I find if the problem is from DNS or timeout? Using Linux shell.

Youssef

Comment: Please show what have you tried?

Comment: This is best asked over on server fault unless your using code to do the above. Anyway I suggest you Google for the commands nslookup or dig. You want to issue a lookup from your host to a DNS server and confirm it knows how to map your I.P Address to a domain name.

Comment: I tried ping, but I am still struggling to understand it.

Comment: ServerMonkey I will do this next time I have a server fault, it is working fine now :), nslookup or dig looks good I will read about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
ping Your_adress_IP
```

If it failled : you have a timeout problem
Else :

```
ping domaine_name
```

If it failled : you have a DNS problem.

Comment: Thanks, easy and simple.

Comment: You're welcome. If it's solve your problem, can you check valid my answer ?